# checking the state of checkbox using PHP (For t's & c's)

Tags: php, html, checkbox, logic

I am abit stuck on getting the state of a checkbox via PHP. I have spent the past 2 hours on google trying different methods but nothing seems to work...

Basically I need the logic to say "if it is not checked, add an error".

I have tried the following methods:

```
if(!isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions'])){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}

if(isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions']) && $_POST['terms_and_conditions'] == 'true'){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}

if(!isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions']) && !$_POST['terms_and_conditions'] == 'true'){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}

if($_POST['terms_and_conditions'] == "false"){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}

if($_POST['terms_and_conditions'] == false){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}
```

and here is the code for the checkbox:

```
<div id="field">
    <input type="checkbox" value="false" name="terms_and_conditions" id="terms_and_conditions"/>&nbsp;<label for="terms_and_conditions">By clicking this you agree to this site's <a href="terms_and_conditions.php">Terms and Conditions</a></label>   
</div>
```

am I being stupid and going wrong somewhere? It will only put the error out using this method and if the box IS checked (which is needed):

```
if(isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions'])){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}
```

But then if I try make it a negative, ie: with an exclamation mark "!" it displays nothing?

What would be my best way to get around this?

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE**

Here is the register.php file:

```
<?php 
require 'core/init.php';
include_once 'includes/files/overall/header_main.php'; 

$error_array = array();

if(Input::exists()) {

if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();

        try {
            $user->create(array(
                'username'  => Input::get('username'),
                'password'  => $bcrypt->hash(Input::get('password')),
                'name'      => Input::get('name'),
                'joined'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'group'     => 1
            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
            Redirect::to('index.php');

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<section id="aside">
<aside class="register">

</aside>
</section>

<section id="main_content">
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p class="bigger">Join 1000's of <b>docimes</b> and meet new companions - it's easy!</p>
<?php
    if(!empty($error_array)){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($error_array as $error){
            echo '<li>'. $error .'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>" placeholder="name" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('surname')); ?>" placeholder="Surname" />
    </div>
    <div id="field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="password_again">Password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" value="" placeholder="Password again" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Signup" />

    <div id="field">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" name="terms_and_conditions" id="terms_and_conditions"/>&nbsp;<label for="terms_and_conditions">By clicking this you agree to this site's <a href="terms_and_conditions.php">Terms and Conditions</a></label>

    </div>
</form>
</section>

<?php   
include_once 'includes/files/overall/footer_main.php'; 
?>
```

and the validate.php class:

```
<?php
class Validate {
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);

            if($rule === 'required' && $rule_value === true && empty($value)) {
                $this->addError("{$item} is required.");
            } else if (!empty($value)) {

                switch($rule) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get('users', array($item, '=', $value));
                        if($check->count()) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} is already taken.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'accepted':
                        if($rule === 'accepted' && $rule_value === true){
                            $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
                        }
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    if(empty($this->_errors)) {
        $this->_passed = true;
    }

    return $this;
}

protected function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}

public function errors() {
    return $this->_errors;
}
}
```

Comment: change `value="false"` to `value="true"`

Comment: What is the problem with your first method (`!isSet($_POST[..]))`)? Works fine on my system. You might also want to edit the checkbox's value as suggested

Comment: checkboxes don't post if they are not checked. var dump post to see. your first condition should work.

Comment: `(!isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions'])) ? $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions") :'';`

Comment: @JustinWood I tried that and get the same result as explained in my post

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox's value is getting set to `false` when the user checks it.  Because in your HTML you have `<input type="checkbox" value="false"`.  You need `value="true"` if you want the value to be `true` when the user checks it.

However,  with your current code the second and last error should execute when the user does not check the checkbox but you are saying that they don't.  You'll have to double check that.

Comment: I tried this, but then it displays nothing still. how do I compare it in the logic that gets if it is NOT checked, output the error? and putting the '!' infront of the `isset` still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Don't test for == true (actually the default value when checked will be "on". If the checkbox is checked it will show with isset.

```
if(!isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions'])){
    $this->addError("You must agree to our terms and conditions");
}
```

What does print_r($_POST) show after posting with it checked?
To default the checkbox to off, just leave value blank.

---

**UPDATE**
[From here:](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_VALUE.html) VALUE does not effect the checked state of checkboxes. If you want a checkbox to default to on, use CHECKED. Instead, VALUE sets the value that is sent to the server if the user checks that checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked, no value of any kind is sent to the server (`isset() == false`). By default, checkboxes send on.

If you are not getting this value, Following is a completely simplified version of your code so you can see what should happen. When user clicks the checkbox, the post will come back with `$_POST['terms_and_conditions']=='on'` You can then work on adding pieces of your code back in to see what is not working.

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<p class="bigger">Join 1000's of <b>docimes</b> and meet new companions - it's easy!</p>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo 'name'; ?>" placeholder="name" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo 'surname'; ?>" placeholder="Surname" />
    </div>
    <div id="field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo 'email'; ?>" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo 'username'; ?>" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <div id="field">
        <label for="password_again">Password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" value="" placeholder="Password again" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo 'abc'; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Signup" />

    <div id="field">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms_and_conditions" id="terms_and_conditions"/>&nbsp;<label for="terms_and_conditions">By clicking this you agree to this site's <a href="terms_and_conditions.php">Terms and Conditions</a></label>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it doesn't display anything whatsoever

Comment: Post your form statement e.g. `<form method='post' ...>` Make sure your method is post. If your `$_POST` is empty, it sounds like you have it set to 'get'

Comment: In order for `$_POST` to be coming back completely empty, something must be off with your form or testing. At the very least you submit button would show a value in the `$_POST`. I suggest updating your post with the complete form and the code to receive the post. That way I or another can quickly see what is wrong or test it ourselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I removed the class code and retained the form. I put `var_dump($_POST)` at the very top of the form and it brought back the following with a post and the checkbox checked. I suggest you put in debug code at various points along the way to see what is going on.
  `'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
  'surname' => string 'surname' (length=7)
  'email' => string 'email' (length=5)
  'username' => string 'username' (length=8)
  'password' => string '' (length=0)
  'password_again' => string '' (length=0)
  'token' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  'terms_and_conditions' => string '' (length=0)`

Comment: Yes, but I cannot target it if it is NOT checked

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When it is not checked, `isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions'])` will return false. What else are you looking for? I don't even see this test in the code you posted. Where are you evaluating the test for the `$_POST['terms_and_conditions']`?

Comment: If I put in isset($_POST['terms_and_conditions']), if I try to make it false, nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

**Never give value of checkbox as TRUE or FALSE.**

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="something" name="terms_and_conditions" >
                          -----------^
```